# How to download the latest log of a Bamboo job?

Tags: bamboo

I want to download the latest log of a Bamboo job programmatically to parse its content and display in a dashboard.

However, Bamboo does not provide a direct link (e.g. with "latest" in URL similar to artifacts download) or to make the Bamboo build log as an artifact.

Someone who has worked around this issue, please share the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the REST API offered for bamboo builds: https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/6.0.0/

Here's one example from Atlassian's community: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-do-you-get-the-build-log-using-REST-API/qaq-p/485212

See "expand": https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/6.0.0/#d2e485

> ... expands build result details on request. Possible values are: changes, metadata, artifacts, comments, labels, jiraIssues, stages, **logEntries**. stages expand is available only for top level plans. It allows to drill down to job results using stages.stage.results.result. logEntries and testResults are available only for job results

Answer (score 1):

At least as of Bamboo 6.7.1 (and possibly earlier versions), you can issue a request directly for the log using a Script Task, `curl`, and Bamboo variables:

```
curl -X GET --user username:password \
"http://localhost:8085/download/${bamboo.buildKey}/build_logs/${bamboo.buildResultKey}.log"
```

That will give you the textual output of the log.